# JavaScript: Cannot read property 'value' of null from textbox

Tags: javascript

```js
function create(param) {

    var i, target = document.getElementById('results');
    target.innerHTML = '';

    for(i = 1; i <= param; i += 1) {
 target.innerHTML +='<br>'
  for(var j=1;j<=param;j+=1)
        target.innerHTML += '<input type="text" id="a'+i+''+j+'" placeholder="a'+i+''+j+'">';
    }
}
function saveData(param) {
 var a = []
 for(var i = 1;i<param;i+=1) {
 a[i] = [];
 for(var j = 1;j<param;j+=1)
  a[i][j] = document.getElementById('"a'+i+''+j+'"').value;
  }
  var target = document.getElementById('ShowResults');
  for(var i = 1;i<param;i+=1){
  a[i] = [];
  target.innerHTML +='<br>'
  for(var j = 1;j<param;j+=1)
  target.innerHTML +=a[i][j];
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="create(5)" style="widht:300px;height:30px;">Create table</button>

<div id="results"> </div>

<button id="takeResults" onclick="saveData(5)"style="widht:300px;height:30px;">Save data</button>

<div id="ShowResults"> </div>
```

Ok so i made a table whit js and gave every textbox id of `"a'+i+''+j+'"`  but it seems that when i want to save the data it show's me the following error: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Can you guys tell me what i did wrong?

Comment: your have a mistake `getElementById('"a'+i+''+j+'"').value` should be `getElementById('a' + i + '' + j).value;`

Comment: now it gives me undefined at every single value

Comment: edit your question then or post an other one

Comment: I was just asnwering your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52501713/load-only-x-items-in-firebase-recycler-adapter).

Comment: @AlexMamo Sorry I deleted it by mistake and had something to do and forgot about it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution with some code improvements
As i said in the comment, you had a mistake in the code you `getElementById('"a' + i + '' + j + '"')` should be `getElementById('a' + i + '' + j)`
and there's a lot of unnecessary loops

```js
function create(param) {

  var target = document.getElementById('results');
  target.innerHTML = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < param; i++) {
    target.innerHTML += '<br>'
    for (var j = 0; j < param; j++)
      target.innerHTML += '<input type="text" id="a' + i + '' + j + '" placeholder="a' + i + '' + j + '">';
  }
}

function saveData(param) {
  var target = document.getElementById('ShowResults');
  target.innerHTML = '';
  var a = []
  for (var i = 0; i < param; i++) {
    a[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < param; j++) {
      target.innerHTML += document.getElementById('a' + i + '' + j).value;
    }
    target.innerHTML += '<br>'
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="create(5)" style="widht:300px;height:30px;">Create table</button>

<div id="results"> </div>

<button id="takeResults" onclick="saveData(5)" style="widht:300px;height:30px;">Save data</button>

<div id="ShowResults"> </div>
```

Comment: Ok thx now it works :) Thank you a lot :D you saved my mark :D

Answer (score 0):

Change this...

```
a[i][j] = document.getElementById('"a'+i+''+j+'"').value;
```

to this...

```
a[i][j] = document.getElementById('a' + i + j).value;
```

You have two lots of quotes around the id when you create it, but you don't need to add them both when you're using `getElementById`.  Just build the string and it will work.

There were some other issues with your code, mainly where you didn't have opening braces but you had closing braces.  Copy/paste this and it should fix your issues...

```
function create(param) {
    var i, target = document.getElementById('results');
    target.innerHTML = '';
    for(i = 1; i <= param; i += 1) {
    target.innerHTML +='<br>'
    for(var j=1;j<=param;j+=1) {
        target.innerHTML += '<input type="text" id="a'+i+''+j+'" placeholder="a'+i+''+j+'">';
    }
}

function saveData(param) {
    var a = []
    for(var i = 1;i<param;i+=1) {
        a[i] = [];
        for(var j = 1;j<param;j+=1) {
            a[i][j] = document.getElementById('a' + i + j).value;
        }
        var target = document.getElementById('ShowResults');
        for(var i = 1;i<param;i+=1) {
            a[i] = [];
            target.innerHTML +='<br>'
            for(var j = 1;j<param;j+=1) {
                target.innerHTML +=a[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Incidentally, using multiple layers of arrays can cause issues, mainly due to being unfriendly for the reader (or you in the future).  I'd highly recommend using an array of objects instead, and naming things more appropriately than `a`, `i` & `j`.

Comment: It shouldn't do.  Can you check you've changed it to exactly what I posted?

Comment: yeah i did change exactly

Comment: Check the code I just posted.  There were several other issues.